# create iframes with jquery each function

Tags: jquery, iframe

I need to create an iframe for each input on a page, but all of them must be in different variables. So, the iframes' vars must be the inputs' names.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$("input").each(function () {

         var name = $(this).attr("name");

name = document.createElement("iframe");name.src = "";name.name = "focus";document.body.appendChild(name);
    });
```

This is my original working iframe create code:

```
var focus = document.createElement("iframe");focus.src = "";focus.style.display = "none";focus.name = "focus";document.body.appendChild(focus);
```

I took the input name with `attr()`. I want to create an iframe according to that input name. after that for example I will be able to redirect it by `INPUTNAME.src`

How can I create specific iframes according to input names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the name of the `<input>`, but then you immediately overwrite it.  Also, since you're using jQuery anyway, it's easier to create elements with it:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  $('body').append($('<iframe/>', {
    src: "",
    name: this.name
  });
});
```

Comment: i clicked but nothing happens. opera by the way.

Comment: by the way if i want to redirect this iframe what will i do in the next parts of the page? in my original code, i could do this with iframe.src. now?